# Show that $ \int f \,\mathrm dx = \text{lim}\int f_n\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: real-analysis

I need help with the following:

Let $f_n \ge 0$ be measurable, lim $f_n = f$ and $f_n \le f$ for each n. Show that $ \int f\,\mathrm dx = \text{lim} \int f_n \,\mathrm dx$

I am trying to establish that 
$$ \lim \int f_n \,\mathrm dx \le \int f \,\mathrm dx \le \lim \int f_n \,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: Where have you used $g$ in the question?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo.

Comment: Aha, then the answer below is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Fatou's Lemma, $\int f \,\mathrm dx \leq \liminf \int f_n\,\mathrm  dx$. Hence, $\int f \,\mathrm dx \leq \liminf \int f_n \,\mathrm dx \leq \limsup \int f_n\,\mathrm dx \leq \int f\,\mathrm  dx$. So $\int f\,\mathrm  dx=\lim \int f_n \,\mathrm dx$.